# Validate value based on another value using class-validator with nestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm having issues validating a field nested in an object, but the condition is based on another field in the parent object.

```
export class NotificationInput {
  @Expose()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    type: ContentInput,
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Type(() => ContentInput)
  content: ContentInput;

  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: [Destination],
  })
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Type(() => Destination)
  @ArrayMaxSize(50)
  destinations: Destination[];
}

export class ContentInput {
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotBlank()
  message: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotBlank()
  type?: string;
}

export class Destination {
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotBlank()
  user: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotBlank()
  notificationType: string;
}
```

Is there a way that I can only validate the `type` field in `ContentInput` if all the `notificationType` in destinations are 1 specific value ("SMS" for example)? Like using `ValidateIf` on `type` field but with values from `destinations`?

ex1:

```
// type will not be validated if input looks like this
{
  "content": {
    "message": "message"
  },
  "destinations": [
    {
      "user": "user1",
      "notificationType": "SMS"
    },
    {
      "user": "user2",
      "notificationType": "SMS"
    }
  ]
}
```

ex2:

```
// type will be validated and returns a BadRequestException
{
  "content": {
    "message": "message"
  },
  "destinations": [
    {
      "user": "user1",
      "notificationType": "Not SMS"
    },
    {
      "user": "user2",
      "notificationType": "SMS"
    }
  ]
}
```